# Hiding Xvfb Teminal Logs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

Every time I execute my tests in headless firefox using Xvfb I get large chunk of logs. These logs display different parameters and their values .

I was wondering if I can disable these logs somehow, I googled a bit but could not find anything useful

Following logs are displayed and I want to disable these.

```
`5 XSELINUXs still allocated at reset
SCREEN: 0 objects of 168 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DEVICE: 4 objects of 96 bytes = 384 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 152 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 32 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 5 objects, 400 bytes, 0 allocs
4 DEVICEs still allocated at reset
DEVICE: 4 objects of 96 bytes = 384 total bytes 0 private allocs
CLIENT: 0 objects of 152 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
WINDOW: 0 objects of 32 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 5 objects, 400 bytes, 0 allocs
1 PIXMAPs still allocated at reset
PIXMAP: 1 objects of 16 bytes = 16 total bytes 0 private allocs
GC: 0 objects of 56 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
CURSOR_BITS: 0 objects of 8 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
DBE_WINDOW: 0 objects of 24 bytes = 0 total bytes 0 private allocs
TOTAL: 1 objects, 16 bytes, 0 allocs
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Did not find a clean solution to disable them so I included a pre-build task in Jenkins to clean those log files before running the automated tests.  And as my automated tests are launched very regularly by Jenkins, logs are often cleaned. This way I don't risk any disk-full issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to resolve this problem. I would first suggest initializing Xvfb in a separate terminal from where you're running your code. Xvfb log messages will be dumped in the terminal it's running in.

Another solution would be to use a wrapper. If for example you're coding in python, you could try `https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You can get those Verbose messages to go away if you re-direct the log output from Xvfb to /dev/null.

In my case, I was using Xvfb plugin in Jenkins and running Selenium tests using Firefox on a CentOS machine. Got the same verbose messages.

I resolved it by UN-CHECKING one of the box which was for "Logging Xvfb log output" --OR

you can also do it as at the $ or # prompt:

`/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1600x1200x16 2>/dev/null 1>&2 &`